# Converting a list of Strings to an array using .ToArray()

Tags: c#, toarray, iqueryable.toarray

When using the `.ToArray()` function is it necessary to implicitly define the size of the array in order to hold of the characters that were in the list you're converting?

```
String [] array = List.ToArray();
```

I tried doing this because I needed to use the `.GetValue()` ability of the array, however, the array is maintaining a size of 1 and not holding the material from the list. Am I trying to use the `.ToArray()` incorrectly?

```
colAndDelimiter = new List<string>();
colAndDelimiter.Add(text);

String [] cd = colAndDelimiter.ToArray();
```

This is all of the code I have that effects the array. When I `Console.WriteLine()` the list it gives me the entirety of the text. I may be confused about how list works. Is it storing everything as a single item, and that's why the array only shows one place?

Comment: Have you debugged to make sure the list definitely contains more than a single item?

Comment: You're doing it right something else is wrong

Comment: Code looks fine, can you post a more complete example that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: what does the list contain? Can you show us what list looks like

Comment: are you looking to split the characters?if so you can just do text.ToArray()

Comment: what is the value of text..? can you post a sample

Comment: @user1993843 for christ sake, at least try to format your posts.

Comment: @CodeIgnoto I think you mean [`ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx)

Comment: Show what the Text on one line looks like .. sounds like you will need to do a string.Split() when assigning the string[] CD into items that can be Indexed by position

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to convert it to an array to get specific characters out.

Just use `text[index]` to get at the needed character.

If you really need it as an array, use [`String.ToCharArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x.aspx) - you want an array of `char` not an array of `string`.

Edit:

> Is it storing everything as a single item, and that's why the array only shows one place?

Yes, yes it is. You're making a list of `string`s which contains one `string`: the entire contents of `text` - what it seems that you want is to split it up letter by letter, which is what the above methods will achieve.

Answer (score 2):

It should work fine, but try the `var` operator to be sure.

```
var array = List.ToArray();
```

Is there a reason to use `Array.GetValue` instead of the built in functions of the `List<T>` itself
EG:

```
 string value = List.ElementAt(1);
 var values = List.GetRange(0, 5);
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is fine.. but lets say that you are not sure of the size of the 
`string[] cd` then you can do something like the following

```
var colAndDelimiter = new List<string>();
colAndDelimiter.Add(text);
String[] cd = { }; 
cd =  colAndDelimiter.ToArray();
```

find the position of the data in cd 
    string value = cd[0];

Update:
If you want to do this based on values being stored in a single line then you can do this without having to declare the `cd` variable as  `string[] cd;`

```
var colAndDelimiter = new List<string>();
colAndDelimiter.Add("Hello, World, Week, Tuesday");
var cd = colAndDelimiter[0].Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as your `List` object is some IEnumerable (or similar) that has items in it, this should indeed convert your List to an Array.

Note that once you have created this array, adding elements to List won't also add it to the Array